# Proof that $\left(\bigcup_{i}^{}A_i\right)^{\mathsf{c}}=\bigcap_{i}^{}A_i^{\mathsf{c}}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Here is my attempt. Do I have a correct approach?

[image]

Comment: Well, not always, the index set is finite (or even countable). You will have to prove it for arbitrary index set. But, if the given index set is finite, then your approach is correct!

Comment: your idea is good. The for all quantifier ($\forall$) and the existence quantifier ($\exists$) will help you.

Comment: Okey, so if the index set is finite - the proof is correct? How would one make an approach when it comes to arbitrary index sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend your approach to the case where there are infinitely many $A_i$, we'll use quantifiers:$$x\in\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right)^c\iff x\not\in\bigcup_i A_i\iff\forall i (x\not\in A_i)\\\iff\forall i (x\in A_i^c)\iff x\in\bigcap_i A_i^c.$$

Comment: Could one use the notation $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ ?

Comment: You could, but that assumes the indexing set is countable infinite.  To be clear, let the indexing set be denoted $I$.  Then $I$ is finite if $I=\left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$ (your original proof).  $I$ is countably infinite if $I=\left\{1,2,3,...\right\}$ (your example of $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}$). To be most general, we choose an arbitrarily infinite set $I$ and say $\cup_{i\in I}$

Comment: Okey I think I've got it! Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $x\in \left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right)^c$ then by definition $x\notin \bigcup_{i}A_i$ and $x\notin A_i$ for all $i$. Thus we have that $x\in A_i^{c}$ for all $i$ and must then be in intersection of the complements i.e. $x\in\bigcap_{i}A_i^c$.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose $x\in\bigcap_{i}A_i^c$ then $x\in A_i^{c}$ for all $i$. By defintion of the complement $x\notin A_i$ and $x\notin \bigcup_{i}{A_i}$ then we must have $x\in \left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right)^c$.