# Proof verification: $\left(\bigcap_{i}A_i\right)^\mathsf{c}=\bigcup_{i}A_i^\mathsf{c}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

> $ \left( \bigcap _ { i } A _ { i } \right) ^ { \mathrm { c } } = \bigcup _ { i } A _ { i } ^ { \mathrm { c } }$
>
> $x \in \left( \bigcap A _ { i } \right) ^ { \mathrm { c } } \Leftrightarrow x \notin \bigcap _ { i } A _ { i }$
>
> $x \notin \bigcap _ { i } A _ { i } \Leftrightarrow \left( x \notin A _ { 1 } \vee x \notin A _ { 2 } \vee \cdots \vee x \notin A _ { n } \right)$
>
> $\left( x \notin A _ { 1 } \vee x \notin A _ { 2 } \vee \cdots \vee x \notin A _ { n } \right) \Leftrightarrow \left( x \in A _ { 1 } ^ { \mathrm { c } } \vee x \in A _ { 2 } ^ { \mathrm { c } } \vee \cdots \vee x \in A _ { n } ^ { \mathrm { c } } \right)$
>
> $\left( x \in A _ { 1 } ^ { \mathrm { c } } \vee x \in A _ { 2 } ^ { \mathrm { c } } \vee \cdots \vee x \in A _ { n } ^ { \mathrm { c } } \right) \Leftrightarrow x \in \bigcup _ { i } A _ { i } ^ { \mathrm { c } }.  \mathbf { Q E D }$

Is this correct?

Comment: Pretty compact and schematic...but yes: as far as I see, it is *almost*  completely correct. . BTW, the only problem I see is that in the lines 3 to the last one you assumed the number of sets is $\;n\;$ ...this is an unnecessary limitation. Just delete the last $\;A_n\;$ and *do not number up* the sets. The claim is true for **any** cardinality of the indexing set of $\;i\,'$ s.  Only god knows why somebody found this question to be worth a downvote: that seems to be psychopatic... +1

Comment: Okey, that's a relief. Thanks for your response. Also, do you perhaps know how one could prove this without *logical operators* (I don't know what to call them)? A similar proof of $\left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right)^\mathsf{c}=\bigcap_{i}A_i^{\mathsf{c}}$ one could do it accordingly as:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120339/proof-that-left-bigcup-ia-i-right-mathsfc-bigcap-ia-i-math EDT: the answer marked as *useful*

Comment: You can replace all logical operators by plain English. Are you satisfied with it?

Comment: Well of course, but that was not my question.

Comment: You mostly used two logical operators, and the answer you linked uses quantifiers...If you want to get rid of all these do what Yui proposes: plain English (or German, or Spanish, or Chinese or whatever)  is usually fine  just as well/